# How to perform two-sample t-test with Minitab?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, minitab

I am trying to do a few tests in Minitab and I don't understand why they are not working out.

First, my data in minitab has several columns: `Class Name Gender Height Age`, where

- `Class` has two values {A,B};
- `Name` is the name of the students;
- `Gender` is Female or Not female;
- `Age` is the age of the student.

My questions I have to answer are as follows: 
Is the *height* of *Class A* larger than *Class B*?

**My understanding of the question** 
I should be  a 2 sample t-test of the differences of the  *Height* of *Class A* - *Class B*

However, every time I try to do a two sample t-test it just compares class with height, which is silly and doesn't workout.

How Do I get Minitab to test *Class A*'s *height* against *Class B*'s *height*?

Ps.  If I am incorrect in the correct hypothesis testing method, please let me know.

Comment: Many statistical software allow to perform a two-sample t-test where data is organized in two columns with either (a) scores of group 1 in 1st column, scores of group 2 in 2nd column, or (b) all scores in one column and the classification factor in the other. This should help: http://www.ams.sunysb.edu/~kye/ams102/minitab/twottest/twottest.html.

Comment: if you write that up as an answer, I will accept and upvote. Thanks for the hyperlink.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have Minitab so I can't show you the exact syntax or GUI menu actions to perform a t-test for independent samples. However, statistical packages (e.g., R, Stata) generally provide commands to perform a t-test when data are organized as either

1. two series of measurements, one for each group (usually arranged in two columns);
2. all individual measurements in one column, described by group levels in another column.

With the example from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Worked_examples) ("weights of screws that were chosen out of a bucket"), that would mean that scheme 1 looks like:

```
+-----+-----+
|A1   |A2   |
+-----+-----+
|30.02|29.89|
+-----+-----+
|29.99|29.93|
+-----+-----+
|30.11|29.72|
+-----+-----+
|29.97|29.98|
+-----+-----+
|30.01|30.02|
+-----+-----+
|29.99|29.98|
+-----+-----+
```

while for scheme 2 we would arrange data as follows:

```
+-----+-----+
|30.02|A1   |
+-----+-----+
|29.99|A1   |
+-----+-----+
|30.11|A1   |
+-----+-----+
|29.97|A1   |
+-----+-----+
|30.01|A1   |
+-----+-----+
|29.99|A1   |
+-----+-----+
|29.89|A2   |
+-----+-----+
|29.93|A2   |
+-----+-----+
|29.72|A2   |
+-----+-----+
|29.98|A2   |
+-----+-----+
|30.02|A2   |
+-----+-----+
|29.98|A2   |
+-----+-----+
```

As explained on this [short tutorial on Minitab 2-Sample-t-test](http://www.ams.sunysb.edu/~kye/ams102/minitab/twottest/twottest.html), any scheme can be used by filling out the correct option in the `2-Sample-t` dialog box. In your case, that means selecting `Height` as `Samples` and `Class` as `Subscripts`, with `Samples` arranged in one column. After running your t-test, you may want to check usual assumptions (normality and homogeneity of variance).

Answer (score 2):

Two series of measurements can be given in two separate columns as well in Minitab.

Considering the example in [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Worked_examples)

1. Enter two samples in two columns
2. Go to Stat Menu -> Basic statistics -> 2-sample-t-test

And select "samples in different columns".

You can choose "sample is one column" if you have arranged measurements in one column.

[image]

Click "OK".